# Where is the dashboard page of MoonMail?

Tags: moonmail

I set up MoonMail but I can't find the dashboard page to consume the APIs.
My question is: Does MoonMail have any dashboard or I need to make the page to consume the APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a frontend package to interact with the MoonMail backend, [here's what you're looking for](https://github.com/microapps/MoonMail-UI). 
If your question is related to the "commercial" tool, you should contact support so they can give your API key to interact with your MoonMail data.